# Configure which documents types can be created

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

How can I configure what type of documents can be created when a user clicks on the `New` menu item. I want to remove Excel survey and add Wiki page (.aspx). I am using SharePoint Online.

[image: dropdown list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a wiki page in the New button:

- go to site settings -> site content types
- click `Create`
- input site content type:

[image]

- go to the document library -> Library settings -> Advanced settings
- select `Yes` for `Allow management of content types?`
- return to library settings
- under content types section, click `Add from existing site content types`
- select the custom content type you created above.

[image]

Please note if we apply custom content types, the 4 default document templates will disappear by default, so we need to readd the relevant content type which we want to retain.

To achieve that, we need to create custom content types which select Documents as parent content type. In the Advanced settings, we can upload the relevant Excel/PPT template file. And add the custom content type to the library.

Detailed information refer to the links below:

[Set a custom template for a SharePoint library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-a-custom-template-for-a-sharepoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25)

[Default templates in document content type disappear when add a custom content type](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/How-is-the-New-menu-populated-in-document-libraries/td-p/5765)

Comment: This process worked great for my SharePoint Online instance. Thank you.